# Update one Pandas dataframe from another and append rows if needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, outer-join

I have the following dataframes in Pandas:

```
df1:
index  column
1         A1
2         A2

df2:
index  column
2         A2_new
3         A3
```

I want to get the result:

```
index  column
1         A1
2         A2_new
3         A3
```

How do I can achieve this?

df1.update(df2) is not helpful, because I want to see row with index 3 in the result.

Comment: Does `df1 = df2.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index)).fillna(df1)` work for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['A1', 'A2'], columns=['column'], index=[1, 2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['A2_new', 'A3'], columns=['column'], index=[2, 3])
```

`df1`

```
    column
1   A1
2   A2
```

`df2`

```
    column
2   A2_new
3   A3
```

**Code**

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

`output`

```
    column
1   A1
2   A2_new
3   A3
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the most laconic way.

Answer (score 0):

@Ars ML
You can concatenate the two DataFrames vertically and remove duplicates from 'index' column, keeping only the last occurrence of each index value

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2], 'column': ['A1', 'A2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [2, 3], 'column': ['A2_new', 'A3']})

merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['index'], keep='last')
merged_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

outputs as per your desired outcome.

```
1          A1
2      A2_new
3          A3
```

You can also use `merge`, it is more involved but produces your desired outcome.

```
merge_chain = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='index', how='outer') \
                .assign(column=lambda x: x['column_y'].fillna(x['column_x'])) \
                .drop(['column_x', 'column_y'], axis=1) \
                .set_index('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2])
out[~out.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
   column
1      A1
2  A2_new
3      A3
```